# C++ No matching member function for call to 'erase'?

Tags: c++, game-development

Alright, so I am building a game that requires that I am able to add and remove a *Fighter object.

I first declare member variable **fighter** here

```
std::vector<Fighter*> fighter;
```

I then implement Add and Remove like this:

```
void Game::AddFighter(Fighter* f) {

    fighter.push_back(f);
}

void Game::RemoveFighter(Fighter* f) {


    if ( std::find(fighter.begin(), fighter.end(), f) != fighter.end() )
    {
        fighter.erase(f); //Error here
    }

}
```

On the line indicated above, Im getting the error

> No matching member function for call to 'erase'

I understand that the member calling erase must be an iterator, however I don't know how to do that in the context of what I am trying to achieve. I know that the above code works for detecting a `Fighter*` if the `Fighter*` has been added - how do I use the `erase()` function?

Comment: Pop quiz: why do you compare the value returned from `find()` with `fighter.end()`? You must know the answer to this question, since you wrote this, so if you know the answer to this question, you must therefore, logically, know how to get the iterator you're looking for! You actually already know the answer to your question, and by the way how does your C++ textbook describe `find()`'s return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need take the iterator returned by `std::find()` and pass it to `vector::erase()`, eg:

```cpp
void Game::RemoveFighter(Fighter* f) {
    auto iter = std::find(fighter.begin(), fighter.end(), f);
    if ( iter != fighter.end() ) {
        fighter.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void Game::RemoveFighter(Fighter* f) {
    decltype(fighter)::iterator iter;
    if ( (iter = std::find(fighter.begin(), fighter.end(), f)) != fighter.end() ) {
        fighter.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

Which can be re-written as this in C++17 or later:

```cpp
void Game::RemoveFighter(Fighter* f) {
    if ( auto iter = std::find(fighter.begin(), fighter.end(), f); iter != fighter.end() ) {
        fighter.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using C++20 or later, you can use `std::erase()` instead:

```cpp
void Game::RemoveFighter(Fighter* f) {
    std::erase(fighter, f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an iterator to `erase`:

```
    if ( auto it = std::find(fighter.begin(), fighter.end(), f); it != fighter.end() )
    {
        fighter.erase(it); //No error here. If you use C++17.
    }
```

Comment: Note that this requires C++17 or later. If you are using an earlier version, you will have to move the declaration of `it` outside of the `if` statement.